# What does Haskell's Data.Function.on do?

Tags: haskell, combinators

I am finding it hard to find examples of `on` in Haskell and I don't understand the explanation on Hoogle's `Data.Function` page. Please, can I have examples of its use and examples of problems/code where using it makes a solution simpler or more efficient?

Comment: An example is provided on [chapter 7](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules) of LYAH.  Another example is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9319415/6338725). You might want to take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/seVSlKazsNk&t=1595)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose we have a function `f` that takes two arguments. We want a similar function which acts as `f`, but only after both its arguments have been modified by some other function `g`.

We could write a new definition

```
new_f x y = f (g x) (g y)
```

or, exploiting `on`,

```
new_f = f `on` g
```

Nicely, the latter can be used directly, without defining a new symbol `new_f`. (Using a lambda is also viable, but not as nice)

This is typically used with `compare`, a library binary function that checks the ordering between its two arguments. So, we can use

```
sortBy (compare `on` name)   somePeopleList
sortBy (compare `on` age)    somePeopleList
sortBy (compare `on` height) somePeopleList
...
```

to sort according different criteria. Above, we assume that `name`, etc. are functions that can extract the relevant information from a person.

(In more modern Haskell we also have `sortBy (comparing age) somePeopleList`, or even `sortOn age somePeopleList` for the same task)

Answer (score 9):

The type signature for [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) is

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

And, really, there's only one reasonable (non-bottom) implementation of this function.

```
f `on` g = \x y -> f (g x) (g y)
```

Or, written with an infix argument as they do in the GHC source,

```
(.+.) `on` g = \x y -> g x .+. g y
```

So the body of the function is fairly simple. The question is: Why would we care.

The most common use case for `on`, in my experience, is when augmenting sorting or comparing functions with [`compare`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:compare).

In Python, if we wanted to sort a list of people based on their names, we might write

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda person: person.name)
```

Haskell's [`sortBy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy) takes a comparison function to sort by, so we would write the same in Haskell as

```
sortBy (\x y -> getName x `compare` getName y) myList
```

But that's just `on`. So really it's

```
sortBy (compare `on` getName) myList
```

"Sort by comparison on name". It actually reads *almost* like English.

Now, for sorting in particular, this paradigm is *so* common that more recent versions of Haskell provide [`sortOn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn), which takes a Python-style key argument

```
sortOn getName myList
```

But there's a whole collection of ["By" functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:23) that work on lists, and the Haskell devs didn't write "On" variants for each of them.

Some examples:

```
-- Remove entries which have the same name as someone else
nubBy ((==) `on` getName) someList
-- Insert into a list sorted by salary, preserving the ordering
insertBy (compare `on` getSalary) newEmployee employees
-- Find the student with the highest grade
maximumBy (compare `on` getGrade) myStudents
```

So, generally, `on` will be used with a function whose name ends in "By".

Answer (score 1):

Complementing the existing answers, from the viewpoint of some theoreticians, Haskell's [`Data.Function.on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) is an implementation of what some call the [psi](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html#v:psi) [combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic). Quoting [Smullyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Smullyan)<sup>†</sup>:

> A psi bird is a bird Ψ satisfying the condition Ψxyzw = x(yz)(yw)

---

<sub>† Raymond M. Smullyan, [To mock a mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird), Oxford University Press, 2000.</sub>

---

**Related**

- [How can Data.Function's `on` function be generalized to work with n-ary functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43014048/6338725)
- [Implementing Smullyan's arithmetical birds in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21561788/6338725)